# Port forwarding from Mac

Tags: linux, windows, mac, port-forwarding

I have deployed a web application on Windows server and need to access it from Mac. I tried the method below, but it was only for Windows.

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport`

I couldn't find a way to access from Mac.

Note: It is a webapp and it's behind corp firewall and located in restricted zone. So at the moment the webapp is accessible only from the same restricted zone VLAN, not from outside the VLAN.

Comment: I can't figure out quite what you're trying to do here. A web app ought to just be accessible from a browser pointed at the correct URL or IP address. Why do you need port forwarding?

Comment: To access webapp outside of that machine requires firewall port open. That why i'm trying to use port forwarding

Comment: I don't see how the two are connected. A web app should be using known ports anyway & forwarding them is only of concern if you're trying to punch through your router from the outside world. I still can't tell what it actually is you're trying to achieve. It feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Same question as Tetsujin. If on the same network no firewall needs to be involved.  On your mac you shoulld be able to open a browser and go to http://yourwindowserrvername.tld/. That should open the webpage running on that windows server.  If it is running on a different port on the server try http://yourwindowserrvername.tld:1234, where 1234 is the port number you try to access (80 is the default if you specify nothing).